# I need to be able to delete bookings(rows) from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, delete-row

In my DeleteBookings function, I want to be able to delete booking that are stored in rows in a CSV file. I want to be able to delete a certain row off of the file without effecting any of the others.

Every thing I have tried has ended up deleting the entire file itself.

```py
def DeleteBookings():
    username = input("What is your name: ")
    username = username.lower()
    # Open the csv file
    with open('ExistingBookings.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        i = 1
        for row in reader:
            name = str(row[0])
            roomtobook = str(row[1])
            datestart_str = str(row[2])
            enddate = str(row[3])
            timetsart_str = str(row[4])
            endtime = str(row[5])
            if username == name:
                print('\n', 'Meeting:', i, '\n', "Room: ", roomtobook, '\n', "Start Date: ", datestart_str, '\n', "End date: ", enddate, '\n', "Start time: ", timetsart_str, '\n', "End time: ", endtime, '\n')
                i = i + 1
        meetingtodelete = input("What is the number of the meeting you would like to delete: ")
```

This is the data in my CSV

```
john,1,13/08/2019,13/08/2019,1200,1230
jeff,2,13/08/2019,14/08/2019,1230,1100
ben,4,29/08/2019,29/08/2019,1400,1500
```

I want it so that the each meeting is outputted with a specific number. If the user types in this number, that meeting is deleted and that row is written over.

Answer (score 0):

For csv files, I don't think you can delete certain rows, you would have to read in the csv file and output a new csv file. If you need deletions, I would recommend a database of some kind instead.